# How to identify when Vuetify's v-autocomplete reaches last scrolled item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify [v-autocomplete](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/) that I want to know when the user scrolled to its last item, so I can load more items (without him having to type for search):

```
// component.vue
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    ref="myAutocomplete"
    v-model="selectedItem"
    autocomplete="off"
    :items="items"
    no-filter
    :label="$t('unit')"
    rounded
    outlined
    item-text="name"
    return-object
  />
</template>
```

I don't see any available prop and/or event that could help me do that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to listen to scroll events on inner v-automplete's `v-menu__content` element:

```
// component.vue
export default {
  ...,
  // at mounted hook we set the listener
  mounted() {
    const component = this.$refs.myAutocomplete;
    component.onScroll = this.onScroll(component);
  },

  // and our method should look like:
  methods: {
    onScroll(component) {
      // recursively will search for the specified child
      const findChildren = (elem, name) => {
        if (elem.$el.className.includes(name)) return elem.$el;
        let i = 0;
        let children;
        for (i; !children && i < elem.$children.length; i++) {
          children = findChildren(elem.$children[i], name);
        }
        return children;
      }

      // searchs for 'v-menu--content' element inside v-autocomplete
      const vMenuContent = findChildren(component, 'v-menu__content');

      // take its scroll values
      const a = vMenuContent.scrollTop;
      const b = vMenuContent.scrollHeight;
      const c = vMenuContent.clientHeight;

      // check if it is 100% scrolled
      const isScrolled = (a / (b - c)) === 1;
      if (!isScrolled) return
      // reached the last item: load more items...
    },
  },
```